# Python rename; The parameter is incorrect [WinError 87]

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, windows

Estoy haciendo un programa para cambiar el nombre a los archivos de un directorio añadiéndole la fecha y la hora. Aquí el código:

```
import os, time

pth = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\FOLDER\Python\Test')
timestr = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y--%H:%M:%S")

def rename():
    for file in pth:
        while file in pth:
            fil = ('C:/Users/FOLDER/Python/Test/'+file)
            if os.path.isdir(fil): 
                pass
            else:
                st = os.path.splitext(fil)[0] 
                renamefile = (st+'-'+timestr+'.jpg')
                os.rename(fil,renamefile)
                break
rename()
```

Al ejecutarlo obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

```
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:/Users/Desktop/FOLDER/Python/Test/one.jpg' -> 'C:/Users/Desktop/FOLDER/Python/Test/one-17-01-2021--10:04:11.jpg'
```

No logro ver el fallo, alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias.

Comment: En el directorio `Test` hay dos `.jpg`. Con el split intento eliminar la extensión original para que el nombre del archivo no quede tal que así: `one.jpg-17-01-2021--10:04:11.jpg`

Comment: Porque en un nombre de archivo no pueden ir `:`, por eso no te deja ponerlo. Ve a tu escritorio e intenta modificarle el nombre a cualquier cosa poniendo los dos puntos y te dará una lista de caracteres que no puedes usar

Comment: Cierto... no me había percatado. Gracias!!